# AngularJS POST request not rendering resulting HTML

Tags: angularjs, post, express

I am sending form data to an Express server via AngularJS's `$http()` function (see below for relevant code). The server processes the incoming POST data, renders an EJS form via `res.render("some_EJS_view")`, which sends the resulting HTML back to the client.

**Problem:** The client does not render this HTML in the response. I know the client *does* receive the fully-rendered HTML, because I see the HTML in the response using Firefox's Firebug plugin.

**AngularJS code:**

```
// Called when user submits form.
$scope.loginUser = function() {
   $http({
      url: 'http://##.##.##.##:8080/login',
      method: 'POST',
      data: $scope.user // end form data
   });
}
```

However, if I make the request in the browser address bar (of course, changing the server to listen for a `GET` request, and setting dummy values on the server in place of `$scope.user`), the browser renders the HTML as expected.

**How can I have the client render this HTML?** I tried using other functions on the server, like `res.send()` and `res.sendFile()` instead of `res.render()`, but nothing causes the client to automatically render the page.

I may be misunderstanding something fundamental here, but I would appreciate any advice.

Comment: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngBindHtml

Comment: I did see that. But I want to direct the browser to an entirely new page, not insert the HTML code within some element on the existing page. The incoming code _completely_ composes a web page (including opening/closing <html> tags). Any other ideas?

Comment: then redirect in the post route to the new page

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution. Instead of making the server request in JavaScript (AngularJS), I had the *HTML form* directly send data to the server. I directed the form data to the Express route using the `action` HTML attribute. (Now I'm not even using AngularJS.) In this way, the browser automatically renders whatever is sent in the response.